# How to download pdf in Hindi language in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3" package to download pdf. It working fine with English font but when I am trying to download the file with Hindi font it shows ???????.

Controller.php

```
use PDF;
$data = array('name' => 'कृपया');
$pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);
```

Comment: Have you tried this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183558/hindi-font-with-dompdf-in-codeigniter ?

Comment: but im using laravel

Comment: What's the actual problem here. The PDF content or the filename?

Comment: @Abhayjeet it doesn't matter look at the configuration in the answer and give it a try!

Comment: it shows ??????

Comment: Ok.............

Comment: not working.....