# Dompdf URDU font issue

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf, urdu

please any one help, how i print URDU/pakistani fonts on DOMPDF? i used CSS @font-face rules , but not working, show these characters "?????? ????"

Set character encoding to utf 8 but not working, i used following method

[Hindi Font with DOMPDF in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183558/hindi-font-with-dompdf-in-codeigniter)

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/About-Fonts-and-Character-Encoding?fbclid=IwAR1OKwTpmClLL0SsS_sIB2kehHGzXLSH6OHft1ahMIfRRito_BTLC4wPORM